# Django Rest framework- getting total number of rows

Tags: django, count, django-rest-framework

I would like to output a field that counts the number of Candidat in Candidat Model. I am currently using the following serializer:

```
class CountCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Candidat
        fields = ( 'user_count',)   

    def get_user_count(self, obj):
        return Candidat.objects.count()
```

and the following api:

```
class CountCViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Candidat.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountCSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
router.register(r'CountC', CountCViewSet, base_name='users-count')
```

models.py:

```
class Candidat(models.Model):           
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    civility = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthDate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    gouvernorate = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Candidat: {}".format(self.name)
```

But im getting nothing!

[image]

Any help in the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use ``Candidat.objects.all().count() in your ``get_user_count`` function

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo still nothing

Comment: @M1rwen if you put a breakpoint on that line, what is returned by `Candidat.objects.all()`? Does anything get returned?

Comment: Im using sublime text i dont think i can put breakpoints

Comment: The code here should work; the error is likely elsewhere. Can you post all related code here

Comment: Your code seems fine.Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and noticed that `ModelViewSet` generates a count by default. You can see it by navigating to the endpoint in a browser or checking the response body in Postman.

**Example:**

```
{
    "count": 10,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 62,
            "entity_name": "The company name",
            "entity_website_url": "thecompany.com",
            "entity_city": "Los Angeles",
            "entity_state": "CA"
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```